# Does it make sense to add `go mod vendor` to a pre-commit hook?

Tags: go, pre-commit-hook, go-modules, pre-commit, govendor

Setup:

- Our project is using `golang 1.12.14`
- We are using `go build -mod=vendor`

Issue: When new dependencies are added to `go.mod` the vendor folder isn't updated and people are committing code and forgetting to run `go mod vendor` to update the folder. My understanding is that since `-mod=vendor` specifies to use packages from the `vendor` folder, the `go.mod` file will have discrepancies from what we are actually using when building the project.

Question: Should `go mod vendor` be added to a pre-commit hook?

Comment: What would make more sense is `git rm -rf vendor`, and use `go mod` as intended.

Comment: "Should go mod vendor be added to a pre-commit hook?" Maybe, maybe not. You can if this is helping with your problem.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify: I am concerned with adding it because I didn't see anything related to `mod` here which makes me think I have the wrong idea  https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang

Comment: @Flimzy When we upgrade to 1.14 won't we need the vendor folder anyways `When the main module contains a top-level vendor directory and its go.mod file specifies go 1.14 or higher, the go command now defaults to -mod=vendor ` https://golang.org/doc/go1.14

Comment: @DanielKobe: have you tried letting it use a proxy? If all modules are public (which I assume they are if a simple `go mod vendor` works) the default proxy is extremely fast, and sometimes faster than committing large dependency trees to git.

Comment: You don't need the vendor folder with Go 1.11 or newer, if you're using modules. The default for `-mod` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

As of Go 1.14, the `go` command automatically checks for consistency between the `vendor` directory and the `go.mod` file whenever the `vendor` directory is used. In addition, it uses the `vendor` directory by default if the module specifies `go 1.14` or higher (see https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.14#go-command).

As of today, the oldest supported version of the Go toolchain is Go 1.15.13.

So if you upgrade to a supported version of the Go toolchain, it should not be necessary to run `go mod vendor` as a pre-commit hook. The `go` command itself will flag inconsistencies whenever the `vendor` directory is used.